# Sum Function and Changing the type of Variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

I'm using SQL Server Express for my project. I have a table like:

```
Number     Name     Surname     Point     Position
------     ----     -------     -----     --------
1          John     Black       10000     True
2          Jane     Lincoln     8800      True
3          Edward   Payne       17000     False
ETC...
```

I would like to prepare a query that will sum the `Point` where the position is true

```
SELECT Sum(Point) AS Exp1
FROM   DataTable
WHERE  Position = True
```

My problem is the type of `Position` is `Nvarchar`. So the query doesn't sum the `Point` s. I tried the change the type `Nvarchar` to `int`, but I have a big project and it give several errors. Is there any way to make a query to sum the `Point` ?

(I've tried to use `Sum(Var(Point))` but not work)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So instead of applying yet another band-aid to fix a problem now - you should take the time to investigate **why** there are error when trying to convert this column to `INT`, and fix those problems so that you *can* convert this column to the appropriate datatype!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
select sum(CAST(Point AS INT)) as Exp1 from DataTable where position = 'True'
```

or

```
 select sum(CONVERT(int, Point)) as Exp1 from DataTable where position = 'True'
```